# Issue with Craft license not validating

Tags: license

I've recently built a site on Craft, and while developing it locally I had purchased a license for Craft Client. After publishing the website to the production server the administration panel is showing a modal window with the text "You're running Craft Client with a Craft Personal license."

I've checked and made sure the license.key file is where it's supposed to be, and that the file is accessible. I've built a couple of websites on Craft before and have not had this issue until now.

I've tried re-uploading the site to a different server/domain, and it said in the admin panel that the license didn't belong to this domain, but the other domain it was originally uploaded under. So it obviously is reading the license file. I clicked to transfer the license to the new domain, and the same issue started occurring (modal window the the message "You're running Craft Client with a Craft Personal license. What would you like to do?").

As Craft initially read the license file (otherwise how would it know that the site didn't belong to the domain?), it means the license file exists and is valid, so I suspect it's an issue on Craft's side. Unfortunately their support is taking a little long so I thought I'd come to the community to hopefully get some help.

Thanks, Ben.

---

**Edit:** From what I remember from a year ago, this was entirely my own fault. I had purchased the license on the staged version of the site. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try clearing your cache, and/or emptying the contents of the `/craft/storage/runtime/` folder. If it's just some cached data causing a problem, that would fix it.

Otherwise, I'd recommend waiting for P&T to get back to you... they're really the only ones who can *verify* and *correct* your licensing issues.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I've tried clearing the cache and runtime files and while the modal window goes away initially, it comes back on the next page reload.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, was just hoping to get some insight into this ASAP as I'm on a deadline at work (this site is supposed to be live today) and I'm not really getting anywhere with their support staff yet.

Comment: Not much you can do at this point except wait for P&T. On the plus side, none of those issues will affect anything on the **front-end** of your website... those warnings are only interrupting the experience on the back-end.

Comment: That is true (Craft is awesome like that), I suppose I will just have to explain to the client that they can't access the backend just yet. Thanks for you help

Comment: Responded to your support ticket 2 hours ago, but in case you didn't see it, send in your license.key file to support so we can look it up on our end.